# MySQL server is not able to configure on Windows 7

Tags: mysql

I am trying to configure the MySQL server using the MySQL Server installed. However, the configuartion is failing in the installer. Here are the details the installer is showing, but there's no clirity on how to get it fixed.

```
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:6 - Looking for valid template
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:12 - Found valid template.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:18 - Attempting to process template.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:25 - Processed template.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:31 - Attempting to configure service.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:37 - Configured service.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:43 - Attempting to start service.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:100 - Unable to configure service.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:100 - Product configuration controller finished configuration.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:6 - Looking for valid template
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:12 - Found valid template.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:18 - Attempting to process template.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:25 - Processed template.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:31 - Attempting to configure service.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:37 - Configured service.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:43 - Attempting to start service.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:100 - Unable to configure service.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:100 - Product configuration controller finished configuration.
```